# How do I fix this, Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm making a raspberry pi project where I press a button and a distance sensor tells me the distance of where I point the sensor.

When I click the button, I get the distance, then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/ButtonTestingWithDistanceSensor.py", line 18, 
in <module>
    input_state = GPIO.input(buttonPin)
RuntimeError: You must setup() the GPIO channel first
```

and here's my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

buttonPin = 17
TRIG = 4
ECHO = 27

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(TRIG, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(buttonPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
input_state = GPIO.input(buttonPin)
GPIO.setup(buttonPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
if input_state == False:
    GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == False:
        start = time.time()

    while GPIO.input(ECHO) == True:
        end = time.time()

    sig_time = end-start

    #Center Meters

    distance = sig_time / 0.000058 # inches: 0.000148

    print("Distance: {} cm".format(distance))

    GPIO.cleanup()
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Move all your setup code up to the top, outside your `while` loop - it only needs doing once.

Comment: Please put a bit more effort into your question title. It should describe your specific problem and/or ask a specific question. This one is far too generic. Not only are accurate question titles better for the site and for other people trying to find the answers, but they're also better for you---they increase the odds that people will click on your question and try to answer it! You can find some tips on writing good question titles [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your issue is that you run GPIO cleanup in your if condition.

```
GPIO.cleanup()
```

This stops the GPIO channel completely, and you have to run the setup again.

Remove these two statements from your While loop and the code should work as you expect to

Line 1

```
GPIO.setup(buttonPin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
```

Line 2

```
GPIO.cleanup()
```